# Error trying to create randomness in a genetic algorithm

Tags: python, numpy

I'm stuck trying to introduce random mutations into my algorithm.

Here is my code and the error:

```
features = 10
mutateRate = 0.2
mutateSize = 0.01

dad = np.random.rand(features,1)
r1 = np.random.rand(features,1)
child = np.where(r1 <= mutateRate,max(dad + np.random.uniform(-1*mutateSize,mutateSize),0),dad)

 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-9157d0534b46> in <module>()
      6 r1 = np.random.rand(features,1)
      7
----> 8 child = np.where(r1 <= mutateRate,max(dad + np.random.uniform(-1*mutateSize,mutateSize),0),dad)
 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I'm trying to give each element in dad a 20% chance of mutating otherwise the element just comes from original dad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the usage of the `max` function, I believe. I think you're trying to make sure that the values in that matrix never dip below 0 (which is very unlikely given the fact you are using `numpy.random.rand` which is uniformly random.

Here's a snippet of code that should work:

```py
child = np.where(r1 <= mutateRate,np.clip(dad + np.random.uniform(-1*mutateSize,mutateSize), 0, None),dad)
```

Using the `np.clip` method, we can clip the minimum value to be `0`, which should satisfy what you needed.

Comment: The way I'm using np.random.uniform should make negative numbers possible because it ranges between -1*mutateSize and mutateSize, ie. -0.01 and 0.01 I think?

Comment: Yes but the chances that `dad` is exactly less than `0.01` is very very slim, and that is the only scenario where `dad` would become negative after adding `-0.01`. Nevertheless, this should provide a valid solution.

Comment: Ahhh I see because dad's expected starting value is 0.5 so would take lots of luck to get to zero. Sorry, brain fart thanks.

Comment: Exactly! No worries. Let me know if the code snippet works or not.